# How Can I Give My VPN Clients Internet Access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I have been successful in setting up two OpenVPN servers as follows:

1. Ubuntu1 (**LAN IP:**  172.23.6.148  **WAN IP:**  60.242.175.132)
2. Ubuntu2 (**LAN IP:**  172.23.6.149  **WAN IP:**  60.242.175.133)

Clients connecting to both servers can access my two LAN subnets (172.23.6.0/24 and 172.23.7.0/24).  However, those connecting to Ubuntu2 cannot access the internet.  Below are the routing tables from both servers:

**KERNEL ROUTING TABLE FROM UBUNTU1 (172.23.6.148)**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.23.6.120    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.9.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tinc0
172.23.6.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
172.23.7.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
207.187.53.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

**KERNEL ROUTING TABLE FROM UBUNTU2 (172.23.6.149)**

```
root@ubuntu2:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         50.242.184.134  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.9.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tinc0
50.242.184.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0
172.23.6.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
172.23.7.0      172.23.6.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 br0
207.187.53.0    172.23.6.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 br0
```

Please note that I have full control of the gateway for Ubuntu2 but not for Ubuntu1 (3rd party managed).  What do I need to do to get internet traffic for clients connecting to Ubuntu2?  I'm ready and willing to provide any additional information as requested, thanks.

**EDIT #1:**

Below is what I've added to my firewall rules (in **/etc/ufw/before.rules** just before the ***filter** line):

```
# START OPENVPN RULES

# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Allow traffic from OpenVPN client to br0
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o br0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

# END OPENVPN RULES
```

Comment: You seem to have an IP conflict.  You seem to have specfied the same subnet (`10.8.0.0/24`) for the VPN on both servers.  BTW what does your firewall rules look like?  I assume you must have a MASQ/SNAT rule in there, but does that rule cover the VPN networks?

Comment: Thanks for the observation.  I noticed those two entries as well, but that seems to be by design.  Each time I stop the OpenVPN server, they disappear.  When I restart, they appear - and it happens on both servers - so I'm inclined to believe it's by design.  Also, I've edited my question to show the firewall rule I added in order to masquerade the vpn traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/421315/openvpn-client-can-ping-the-server-but-can-not-ping-www-google-com?rq=1), I changed my firewall rule to SNAT instead of MASQUERADE and it worked:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 60.242.175.133
```

I added this rule to the **/etc/ufw/before.rules** file.  I did note, however, that if I included "*iptables*" in the line, UFW failed to reload.  Anyway, my clients connecting to Ubuntu2 now can get internet access.  Thanks to all who offered suggestions, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

you are Masquerading / natting 10.8.0.0/24, however the requests are most likely coming from 172.23 subnet - its impossible to say for certain however without more details.

You should try natting 172.23.0.0/16 and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks David, but I tried that and it didn't make a difference.  I have found a solution and I'll be posting it shortly as an answer.  Really appreciate the help.